# error splicing file:permission denied

Tags: filemanager

I'm new at `Ubuntu`, I made a copy of all of my important files, from windows, including, pdf's microsoft word documents as well. 
and when I try to copy them to the Ubuntu desktop from my external hard drive, an error message occurs,

```
error splicing file:permission denied
```

I have absolute no idea what to do, but I need my files

Comment: How are you copying them?

Answer (score 1):

There may be folders on your external hard drive that are encrypted. If you attach your external hard drive to a computer that is running Windows and unencrypt the encrypted folders, then the contents of these folders will be readable from Ubuntu.